# How to take backup of partial data in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backup

I am working on a project in Laravel where I have to take backup of the database (mySQL).

I have learned to take backup of entire database or selected tables. But the challenge for me is to take backup of only some rows.

Here is the scenario:

**There are 4 tables**

- users
- posts
- tags
- post_tag

**Their relations**

- user `hasMany` posts and each post `belongsTo` a user
- post `hasMany` Tags and a Tag `hasMany` posts

If if initiate backup of a user (`where userId = 1`), Then I should get a backup file containing all the four tables mentioned above with data related to `userId = 1`.

Also, how to restore the data?

**Updates**

It is a role based application. (There are 2 roles editor and author)

Editor has the privilege to backup and restore data of author.

Comment: it is bug free and easy to use and change.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207052/how-to-backup-export-the-connected-database-database-sql-file-in-laravel/67285015#67285015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an server admin only operation, you may use [iseed](https://github.com/orangehill/iseed) to generate seeding files from your existing data in database. The restoration would be easy through Laravel's [database seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/seeding).

If this is a user operation, then you would probably need to program your own import / export feature. You may use a combination of [`fopen('php://output')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) for the database to csv export. Then you may reference some [available](https://makitweb.com/import-csv-data-to-mysql-database-with-laravel/) [tutorials](https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/how-to-import-csv-in-laravel-and-choose-matching-fields/) to write the csv to database import with Eloquent.

Comment: I need a method which can be implemented on button click.....(please check the question i've updated it).....also... if it's possible using iseed could you please guide me.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Which would be the best approach: Joining all the tables of that user then saving or creating multiple files or creating a query list

Comment: If you, on import, are simply going to recreate everything with the same ID and primary keys, I don't see a need to join the tables before export.

Comment: If, however, you need to import without the keys, then you should probably aggregate a tree-like structure and export as JSON. Joining would be preferable.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and to be patient.