# laravel spatie database backup to google drive on cpanel

Tags: laravel, database-backups

Hi i am using spatie(spatie/laravel-backup) package for database backup. Also using nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive package for google drive upload using laravel schedule command. Here is command code

```
    $schedule->command('database:check')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('backup:clean')->everyMinute();
    $schedule->command('backup:run --only-db')->everyMinute();
```

When i run php artisan schedule:run on my local then i get a zip file on my google drive.But when i run this on cpanel then i didn't get any file in my google drive. Here is code for cron job

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/masumcom/binary.masum3.com/artisan 
schedule:run
```

One command run perfectly but other two not working perfectly

```
$schedule->command('database:check')->everyMinute();
```

Only this one working perfectly

Comment: Did you check the error logs files for any message?

Comment: [2021-01-22 18:30:54] local.ERROR: Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. {"exception":"[object] (Swift_RfcComplianceException(code: 0): Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. at /home/masumcom/binary.masum3.com/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php:355)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/replaceyourdirectoryname/public_html/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

or in any controller try

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
Artisan::call('schedule:run');
dd(Artisan::output()); // here you can see error in or echo Artisan::output();
```

or go to storage/log/laravel.log read error log

or go to `cpanel` open mail check error in your mail

or read
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65890498/14913109

Comment: Thank's. I have already solved the problem. I have checked laravel log and solved the problem. spatie(spatie/laravel-backup) package send email when the command execute. My email credential is wrong that's why causes the error